# How can I return to the app which called my app? Both in iOS and Android platform

Tags: android, ios, flutter

Example with iOS:
I should register an URL scheme or several URL schemes in my app, then tell the third developers to add these URL schemes in their app's white list in Info.plist with key `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`, then call `openURL:options:` by `UIApplication` instance. Now they succeeded. But I don't know how to return to these apps after something is done in my app! I have no way to add their URL schemes in advance!

The issue in the Android platform is similar with the iOS.

I noticed that other apps are working well in this business.

This is an example:
https://youtube.com/shorts/NE1gxwhTnA4?feature=share

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9022967/how-can-i-launch-back-the-app-that-opened-my-custom-url-scheme

Comment: You can identify the source application via `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsSourceApplicationKey`. From the received Bundle ID, you can launch the custom URL scheme corresponding to the source application. But this only works for the known URL scheme list that can be found online.

Comment: I know, I can ask the third developers to do this. But I can not add these URL schemes in my app's Info.plist with key `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` when packaging app in advance.

Comment: Why can't you update the `Info.plist` with known URL schemes?

Comment: They are not known! Because the third developers will launch my app in anytime. Perhaps I need a middle web to do this instead. When I want to return, I open the web through `openURL:options:` by UIApplication instance, and tell it to open the previous app such as `xxxapp://xxx.xxx`. I have to bypass this whitelist restriction. I don't know whether built-in browser in app such as `WKWebView` can do this, otherwise the appreance will be different with the social apps such Wechat and Alipay and so on. It will jump to Safari and then jump back to the previous app.